# Prolog family rules

Tags: prolog

I have a few facts:

```
parent(bob, anne). % bob is a. parent of anne.
sibling(anne, mary).
```

I'm trying to get parents from sibling facts, so if I query `parent(X, mary)` bob should be an output. So far my rules are:

```
siblingOf(X,Y) :- sibling(X,Y).
siblingOf(X,Y) :- sibling(Y,X).

parent(X,Z) :- 
    siblingOf(Z,Y),
    parent(X,Y).
```

It goes on an infinite loop. I suspect it is because the recursive call has no end condition. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Your main problem is that `parent/2` is both a fact about `bob` and `anne` and also a rule that recursively calls `parent/2`. `parent(bob, X)` can thus re-enter `parent/2` with the same variables. Rename the rule to something else, like `parentOf/2` the way you did with `siblingOf/2` instead of `sibling/2` and you may have better luck.

Comment: I tried renaming the rule, but it returns false when `parent(X, mary)`

Comment: You're now asking me to help you debug code I can't see. But I think your problem is that you should try `parentOf(X, mary)`, if you followed my advice above.

Comment: The code on my question is the only code. I did exactly what you said, as mentioned in my reply. I renamed the rule to `parentOf`. I will try tinkering more with it, keeping your advice in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already used the same trick: make a predicate with a different name, and thus make sure that you do not call the predicate recursively here:

```
parentOf(P, C) :-
    parent(P, C).
parentOf(P, C) :-
    siblingOf(C, S),
    parent(P, S).
```

We thus say that `X` can be a parent of `Y` based on two conditions:

1. we defined a `parent/2` fact, so *explicitly* mentioned the parent relation; or
2. `P` is a `parent/2` of a `sliblingOf/2` our child `C`.

Then we obtain:

```
?- parentOf(X, Y).
X = bob,
Y = anne ; 
X = bob, 
Y = mary.
?- parentOf(X, mary).
X = bob.
```

Comment: Weird. A few days back when I did this based on Daniel Lyons advice, it doesn't work. But for some reason when I coded it from scratch it now works. Lol.

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz: did you made a recursive call in the last line, so `parentOf(P, S)` instead of `parent(P, S)`?

Comment: I did. It recursed infinitely for some reason. Tested today the (I think) same code but on https://swish.swi-prolog.org/ and worked. I can't investigate if the code was the problem though, it was deleted and I started from scratch. Anyway, thanks!